# How to write a working cmake file for flex & bison?

Tags: cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a small parser, but have problems of using cmake.

My purpose is: flex F.l => F.cc,  bison B.y => B.cc,
my_program.cc + F.cc + B.cc => library

My first attempt:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)
if (FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        flex_target
        COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE} 
            --header-file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.h
            --outfile=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.cc
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.l
        COMMENT "Generating F.cc"
    )
endif(FLEX_FOUND)
FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
if (BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        bison_target
        COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE} 
            --defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.h
            --output=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.cc
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.y
        COMMENT "Generating B.cc"
    )
endif(BISON_FOUND)

add_library(my_library my_program.cc F.cc B.cc)
add_dependencies(my_library bison_target)
add_dependencies(my_library flex_target)
```

Everything is OK except that flex & bison commands are called every time when I run make, even F.l and B.y files are NOT changed.

Then I try to switch to use ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND instead of ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)
if (FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.cc
        SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.l
        COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE} 
            --header-file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.h
            --outfile=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.cc
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/F.l
        COMMENT "Generating F.cc"
    )
endif(FLEX_FOUND)
FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
if (BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.cc
        SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.y
        COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE} 
            --defines=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.h
            --output=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.cc
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/B.y
        COMMENT "Generating B.cc"
    )
endif(BISON_FOUND)

add_library(my_library my_program.cc F.cc B.cc)
```

Note that it seems that I can't add dependencies for ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND.

Then when I run make it seems that flex & bison will only run ONCE. It won't run second time even .l and .y files are changed.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a side issue, but you really shouldn't be using the `-y` bison option, and `-d` is redundant if you specify `--defines`.

Comment: @rici thanks, it's removed in the question.

Answer (score 7):

CMake has module for both [Flex](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFLEX.html) and [Bison](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html), so you could do this:

```
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)

flex_target(lexer F.l "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/F.cc")

bison_target(parser B.y "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/B.cc")

add_library(my_library STATIC
    ${sources}
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/F.cc"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/B.cc"
)
```

Note that both `flex_target` and `bison_target` use `add_custom_command` internally.

**Edit:** For completeness, as @vre points out in comments, there's `FindFLEX` provides `add_flex_bison_dependency` command:

```
add_flex_bison_dependency(lexer parser)
```

Which makes `lexer` depend on `parser`, in order to allow former use tokens from later.

Comment: +1, But I would rather use the suggested names from the `FindFLEX.cmake` example `${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_lexer_OUTPUTS}` than repeating the output names and mention the necessity to add `add_flex_bison_dependency(parser lexer)` in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer (looking at docs, the correct order is `lexer`, then `parser`).

Comment: Ahh, sorry I mixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you need to use `add_custom_command`.
2. Do not output into source dir, use inary dir for that.
3. List input file in the `DEPENDS` section to make CMake track changes and re-run the command whenever it changes.

See the [`add_custom_command` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command) for more info.